# request.session.get('last_visit') yields None all the time

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I am recently into session and cookies. I comprehend session and cookies well in theory but i have one issue in understanding the code of session. It is about getting the last_visit by the user. The code is
from the tangowithdjango.com

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    for category in category_list:
        category.url = encode_url(category.name)

    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
    context_dict['pages'] = page_list

    #### NEW CODE ####
    if request.session.get('last_visit'):
        # The session has a value for the last visit
        last_visit_time = request.session.get('last_visit')
        visits = request.session.get('visits', 0)

        if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(last_visit_time[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).days > 0:
            request.session['visits'] = visits + 1
            request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
    else:
        # The get returns None, and the session does not have a value for the last visit.
        request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
        request.session['visits'] = 1
    #### END NEW CODE ####

    # Render and return the rendered response back to the user.
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

When i tried to understand what request.session.get('last_visit') does,  i get None all the time. What i don't understand is the key 'last_visit'. Is it default object inside session? If it is default in the session object then why it shows None every time in my terminal.

Please someone make me understand the object passed inside get().

Comment: fix your indentation, plz.

Comment: @levi Can you answer it now, please?

Comment: can you post your whole view code ?

Comment: @levi updated the code

Comment: did you add     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 ? to your middlewares ?

Comment: Yes i have and also i have django.contrib.sessions inside INSTALLED_APPS tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `RequestContext` stuff to bottom

```
def index(request):


    #### NEW CODE ####
    if request.session.get('last_visit'):
        # The session has a value for the last visit
        last_visit_time = request.session.get('last_visit')
        visits = request.session.get('visits', 0)

        if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(last_visit_time[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).days > 0:
            request.session['visits'] = visits + 1
            request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
    else:
        # The get returns None, and the session does not have a value for the last visit.
        request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
        request.session['visits'] = 1
    #### END NEW CODE ####

    context = RequestContext(request)

    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    for category in category_list:
        category.url = encode_url(category.name)

    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
    context_dict['pages'] = page_list

    # Render and return the rendered response back to the user.
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/cookie.html . Here RequestContext is at the top. My main question is what is 'last_visit'. Is it buit in object inside sessions object ? How to see what is inside request.session?

Comment: @pythonLover print `request.session.keys()`

Comment: i get only these 3 session dict_keys(['_auth_user_backend', '_auth_user_hash', '_auth_user_id']). From where that 'last_visit' has come to request.session?

Comment: plz post your settings.

Comment: https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django_17/blob/master/tango_with_django_project_17/settings.py

Comment: aforementioned i am learning from the tangowithdjango about session. You can see the code there and its a working code. Thanks

Comment: Looks like its using the default session backend that uses the  database to storing session data. Can you check whether your database has the table 'django_session'. If not, run python manage.py migrate to create it.